# Applying a given mathematical expression on given lists

Tags: python, list, sympy, curve-fitting

I'm working on a python program that should receive two lists (x,y) and a number of functions (in x,y) and then return a list for each of the functions that contains the output of each element in the list, so this is what I tried:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abc import x, y
#Entering the functions
SympF=[]
F=[]
n = int(input("Please enter the number of terms in the general regression formula : ")) 
for i in range(0, n): 
    SympF.append(sympify(input("Insert your functions : \n")))
    F.append (lambdify([x, y], SympF[i]))

#Entering Points
xdata = []
ydata = []
m = int(input("Enter number of elements : ")) 
print('Enter each point as space seperated x & y')
for i in range(0, m): 
    x,y = map(float, input().split())
    xdata.append(x)
    ydata.append(y)

    #making a list for each function (this is where I'm stuck)
    Z=[]
for i in range(0, n): 
    for j in range (0,m):
        Z.append(F[i](xdata[j],ydata[j]))
for item in F:
    print(F);
```

What this code should be doing is give me a list Z that contains the outputs of F[i], F[i+1], F[i+2].... but instead what I get is the error:

```
[<function _lambdifygenerated at 0x00000229CA678438>, <function _lambdifygenerated at 0x00000229CAB31708>, <function _lambdifygenerated at 0x00000229CAB318B8>]
[<function _lambdifygenerated at 0x00000229CA678438>, <function _lambdifygenerated at 0x00000229CAB31708>, <function _lambdifygenerated at 0x00000229CAB318B8>]
[<function _lambdifygenerated at 0x00000229CA678438>, <function _lambdifygenerated at 0x00000229CAB31708>, <function _lambdifygenerated at 0x00000229CAB318B8>]
```

So what am I missing, also is there a better way to do this rather than use a single list Z then split it (get n lists back containing the outputs from the for loop)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at your code. I recommend for you to start using a debugger so you understand what is going on in your scripts :) You were printing the wrong list altogether.
I commented some lines for you. Hope I could help..

```py
import sympy # don't import everything(*)!!
from sympy.abc import x, y

# Entering the functions
SympF = []
F = []
n = int(input("Please enter the number of terms in the general regression formula : "))
for i in range(0, n):
    SympF.append(sympy.sympify(input("Insert your functions : \n")))
    F.append(sympy.lambdify([x, y], SympF[i]))

# Entering Points
xdata = []
ydata = []

m = int(input("Enter number of elements : "))
print("Enter each point as space seperated x & y")
for i in range(0, m):
    x, y = map(float, input().split())
    xdata.append(x)
    ydata.append(y)


Z = [] # Set up a list
for i in range(0, n):
    my_list = [] # for every function initialize a temporary list as empty
    for j in range(0, m): # Calculate the results
        my_list.append(F[i](xdata[j], ydata[j]))
    Z.append(my_list) # Add the list to your result

for item in Z:
    print(item)
```